# How can I store Github token with Git Credential Manager on Ubuntu?

Tags: git, github, git-credential-manager, github-token

With the new Git Credential Manager (GCM) how can I use it to store Github access token on Ubuntu? I have tried to read the usage text and it is not clear how one can store Github token using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it with:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=you\npassword=yourToken" | \ 
  git credential-manager-core store
```

Make sure `git-credential-manager` is in your `$PATH`.
Replace '`you`' with your GitHub account name, and '`yourToken`' by your GitHub token.