# bat file not running git push as generic user in task scheduler

Tags: git, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have set up a schedule in task scheduler to run a bat file containing git commands as a generic user.

This bat file contains the following commands:

```
cd C:\repo
call D:\path\to\git --git-dir=C:\repo\.git add --all > log.txt
call D:\path\to\git --git-dir=C:\repo\.git -c user.name="genericUser" -c user.email="genericUser@email.com" commit --author="genericUser <genericUser@email.com>" -m "message" >> log.txt
echo Pushing changes... >> log.txt
set GIT_TRACE=true
call D:\path\to\git --git-dir=C:\repo\.git push origin main >> log.txt
EXIT /B
```

and the task scheduler properties look like this:

#### General tab

- user account is set to "genericUser"
- "Run whether user is logged on or not" is selected
- "Run with highest privileges" checked

#### Actions tab

- Action set to "start a program"

in the properties of this action:

- program/script is set to `C:\Window\System32\cmd.exe`
- Add arguments set to `/c start "" "C:\repo\commit.bat"`
- Start in set to `C:\repo`

#### Conditions tab

- Default checks in place
- Wake the computer to run this task is checked

When I run the schedule, it runs everything but gets stuck when it hits the git push command.

I have set up the windows credentials for this generic user and have made a successful push as the generic user. git config --global user.name and user.email has been set up for this generic user as well. When running the git commands manually in git bash, I do not get prompted for credentials on git push.

my global .gitconfig looks like this:

```
[credential]
    helper = manager
[user]
    name = genericUser
    email = genericUser@email.com
[commit]
    name = genericUser
    email = genericUser@email.com
```

Comment: put a `2>&1` after each `log.txt` to capture any error messages too and check the logfile for hints.

Comment: If `\git` is supposed to be `git.exe`, then there is no reason to use `call`. If it is supposed to be `git.cmd` or `git.bat` then you should use `call`, but perhaps you'll need to escape the `=` argument delimiters being passed to those batch files. `--git-dir^=C:\repo\.git add --all`, `--git-dir^=C:\repo\.git -c user.name^="genericUser" -c user.email^="genericUser@email.com" commit --author^="genericUser <genericUser@email.com>" -m "message"` and `--git-dir^=C:\repo\.git push origin main`.

Comment: @Compo I have git installed on another drive letter in this case. I'll update the drive letters in my original post. `C:\path\to\git` is the parent folder where the global .gitconfig file is stored. eventually I will be implementing this on a repo that pulls and tracks external files and that was the only solution that worked in task scheduler. I'm keeping it in there for now while testing on this dummy repo that doesn't track external files.  see this previous post by me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77410897/how-do-i-track-files-outside-of-my-git-folder

Comment: @Compo @Mofi @Stephan , I added `2>&1` at the end of each log.txt to grab error messages and it's outputting exactly that, I updated `C:\path\to\git` drive letter to `D:\path\to\git` on the original post as that's the drive it's actually mapped to (my bad), I updated `call D:\path\to\git` to `D:\path\to\git.exe`, I changed `cd C:\repo` to `cd /D C:\repo`, I removed `EXIT /B`, I added escapes `^` to the `=` arguments, and finally I changed the task scheduler properties action arguments from `/c start "" "C:\repo\commit.bat"` to `/D /C C:\repo\commit.bat`.

re-running now.

Comment: after running, I'm seeing this error during the push with trace enabled: `bash: line1: /dev/tty: No such device or address, error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1), fatal: could not read Username for 'https://maskedWebsite.com': No such file or directory`... maskedWebsite.com being our bitbucket source repo url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you can:

- use the full path to `git.exe` instead of `git` or `call D:\path\to\git`. That makes sure the correct executable is called without ambiguity.
- add `2>&1`, to redirect both standard output and error output to `log.txt` for all commands. That will capture any error messages.
- use `cd /D C:\repo` ensures the script will work even if the current directory is on a different drive.
- remove `EXIT /B` at the end of the batch file.
- set variables explicitly, based on the issues with `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` not being set.
- change the Task Scheduler arguments to `/D /C C:\repo\commit.bat` for a more direct call to the batch file.

Your script would be:

```
@echo off
cd /D C:\repo

:: Set environment variables explicitly for Git
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set HOMEPATH=\Users\genericUser
set GIT_TRACE=true
set PATH=%PATH%;D:\path\to\git\bin

:: Capture both standard output and error output for all commands
D:\path\to\git.exe --git-dir=C:\repo\.git add --all >> log.txt 2>&1
D:\path\to\git.exe --git-dir=C:\repo\.git -c user.name="genericUser" -c user.email="genericUser@email.com" commit --author="genericUser <genericUser@email.com>" -m "message" >> log.txt 2>&1
echo Pushing changes... >> log.txt
D:\path\to\git.exe --git-dir=C:\repo\.git push origin main >> log.txt 2>&1
```

Pay extra attention to who is running the script: check the security options of the task to make sure it is running as the correct user.

---

That last part is the crux of the issue: using [GCM (Microsoft Git Credential Manager)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68768432/6309) (with `git config --global credential.helper manager`) means using the Windows *vault* ([Windows Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0)).

Even if you enter the credentials of *another* account in said vault, only *you* (your current account) would be able to read those back.

If your task runs as a generic account, you need to store those credentials in a [`Runas /profile /user:Company\accountName CMD`](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html) session.
There, you will be able to [store credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72529089/6309) that your task will be able to read back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256167/discussion-between-vonc-and-bocodes).