# git unable to index files outside of repo (Permission Denied)

Tags: git, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have been working on setting up a windows task to automatically push all items from a shared network drive folder into an online repository with a domain user account ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586972/bat-file-not-running-git-push-as-generic-user-in-task-scheduler)). I have set up my local git repo outside of this shared network drive folder to prevent other users from running git commands or messing up the repo settings. When my automated task goes to add in the files from outside the repo, I am met with this error:

```
error: open("Path/to/file/I/want/to/add.txt"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file 'Path/to/file/I/want/to/add.txt'
fatal: adding files failed
```

Here is my task configuration:

#### General tab

- user account is set to "domainUser"
- "Run whether user is logged on or not" is selected
- "Run with highest privileges" checked

#### Actions tab

- Action set to "start a program"

in the properties of this action:

- program/script is set to `C:\Window\System32\cmd.exe`
- Add arguments set to `/D /C D:\repo\commit.bat`
- Start in set to `D:\repo`

#### Conditions tab

- Default checks in place
- Wake the computer to run this task is checked

Here is the bat file that is ran by the task scheduler to upload the files from the network drive folder:

```
git config --global user.name "domainUser"
git config --global user.email "domainUser@email.com"
git config --system --add safe.directory D:/repo
set HOMEDRIVE=C:
set HOMEPATH=\Users\domainUser
cd /D D:\repo
D:\path\to\git.exe --git-dir=C:\repo\.git add --all > log.txt 2>&1
D:\path\to\git.exe --work-tree^=//path/to/network/drive/folder add --all > log.txt 2>&1
D:\path\to\git.exe --git-dir=C:\repo\.git -c user.name="domainUser" -c user.email="domainUser@email.com" commit --author="domainUser<domainUser@email.com>" -m "message" >> log.txt 2>&1
echo Pushing changes... >> log.txt 2>&1
set GIT_TRACE=true
D:\path\to\git.exe --git-dir=C:\repo\.git push origin main >> log.txt 2>&1
```

the domainUser also uploads files from the local repo such as the README.md and does not have a "pemission denied" issue with these files. It's only the external files.

please keep in mind that this information has been masked for security reasons.

Comment: We have no idea what your task configuration is. It would be prudent to use the [Edit] facility to update your question with the exact scheduled task settings. You can do that very simply, by opening a Command Prompt window, typing `%SystemRoot%\System32\schtasks.exe /Query /S {machine} /U {user} /P {pwd} /FO List /V /TN "{task name}"`, pressing the `[ENTER]` key, and copying and pasting the output into a code box. Ensure you provide, alongside that, a full explanation of what happens, and all debugging information. It would also be wise to tell us which of your drives are network mapped.

Comment: @Compo the task configuration can be found in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586972/bat-file-not-running-git-push-as-generic-user-in-task-scheduler). I have updated my post here to match

Comment: the only drive that is network mapped is `//path/to/network/drive/folder`

Comment: If a user is not logged in, then a drive is not mapped for them. For this reason you would need to uncheck the option "Run whether user is logged on or not". Also, it is not likely that the System account, which is in effect when "Run with highest privileges" is selected, has any mapped drives, so that should be deselected too.

Comment: @Compo If I deselect these options, the task status will not change from `ready` to `running`. It will only stay as `ready` and does not output any logs when trying to run it manually. For some context, this is a domain user account and does not have the `Allow log on locally` or `Log on as a service` privileges for this machine. It only has `Log on as a batch job`.

Comment: If you have no connection to the network device, and you don't, then nothing will work at all. You must uncheck them, then recode your project.

Comment: @Compo I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can't I use something like `net use DRIVE: PATH` to programmatically add the network drive for the user before running the rest of the bat file? Also how would I re-code the project if it doesn't run with everything unchecked?

Comment: If you had used `net use` it should have been in your code, and you wouldn't have specifically shown `//path/to/network/drive/folder` over ```X:\```. As for mentioning down deep in the conments that this is a domain account, that information should have been included in your question. In such an environment you'd need to grant access to that location to the domain account for the computer where your script is running.

Comment: @Compo some of this context is not in the original post because I simply did not think it would be worth mentioning, so my mistake. Given the comments you have posted, I have supplied said information. Same goes for the net use command. I am researching and learning more as I go. Continuing on, to grant access to the domain account, is this a one-time setup just like mapping any network drive, or would I need add code to my bat file to map the drive on every run?

Comment: After some more research, I found that the network drive we were using could be reached even without being mapped. that's why I was able to see `("Path/to/file/I/want/to/add.txt")` otherwise I would have seen an error along the lines of `The network path was not found`. To add permissions for my domain user to this folder, we had to open the folders properties, go to the security tab, and add it to the users section with modify, read & execute, list folder contents, and read permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The permission issue was resolved by

- navigating to the network drive
- opening the folder I needed permission to
- open the folders properties window
- open the security tab
- add my domain user to the `Group or user names` section
- give my domain user the following permissions: Modify, Read & execute, List folder contents, and Read.

thank you everyone for taking time to help figure this out.